# How's responsible for displaying `Starting ... [ ok ]`

Tags: linux, daemon

When I start a service such as:

```
root@foo [~]# service foobar stop
Stopping Foobar:                                       [  OK  ]
```

I can see a status indicator: `[  OK  ]` which is different from the one visible on `/var/log/boot.log`:

```
[  OK  ] Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
...
```

Or even different from:

```
* /proc is already mounted
* Caching service dependencies ...        [ ok ]
```

In these three examples which process is responsible of displaying and starting the daemons? Said differently, which library is used to display `[  OK  ]`, `[FAILED]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a manual invocation of `service` runs a SysV style script from /etc/init.d or /etc/rc.d, all status output depends **entirely on that script.**

Properly written init.d scripts will use a library of shell functions provided by the distro. For example, in Debian, most scripts will load (source) the file `/lib/lsb/init-functions`, and simply call its provided functions like this:

```
case "$1" in
  start)
    log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_start
    case "$?" in
        0|1) log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  [...]
esac
```

Here's the [list of standard functions](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/iniscrptfunc.html) defined by LSB. (Note that distros may provide *additional* functions beyond the standard, as the example above. Also note that e.g. OpenRC or Arch Linux *aren't* LSB-compatible and use entirely different styles.)

In fact, some distros will provide this boilerplate code centrally as well, and all that's left to the init.d script is to implement `do_start`. (See Gentoo's OpenRC and Debian's `/lib/init/init-d-script` as examples). However, that's not a "standard" LSB feature – scripts trying to be LSB-compatible still have to do it manually.

---

**Note:** I emphasize 'Properly written' because really there's nothing that would *force* an init.d script to use these functions, other than human supervision. If the script wants to report status via plain `echo` (or via `cowsay` for that matter), it is always able to do that. This is especially a problem with commercial software distributed outside the normal channels: their status output *never* looks quite right (and frankly, the whole init.d script never behaves quite right).

---

Meanwhile, when SysV scripts are called during the **boot process**, the result is even more distro-dependent – sometimes you'll see output directly from the scripts themselves, but sometimes the "main" init system will provide its own status output for all services it starts. ([Example:](https://github.com/teg/initscripts-arch/blob/master/functions#L225) Arch Linux's old initscripts, when starting a service in background.)

But your 2nd example is actually *not* a SysV style init – it's systemd (which just happens to be starting a 'legacy' init.d script in your example). Systemd is a full service manager which uses service configurations (not scripts), and therefore *all* boot/shutdown status output is provided by systemd itself. This also applies to most other "service managers", including init-ng, SMF, or Upstart.

Comment: I took a quick look at `/lib/lsb/init-functions`, but when I try to execute `[ 1 != 2 ] && log_end_msg 1` I get `   ...fail!` not `[fail]`. I am a bit confused.

Comment: @nowox: You probably want `log_failure_msg` then. (init.d scripts aren't very consistent in what functions they use. My Debian sid system has a mix of several different styles.)

Comment: @nowox: Indeed the [actual LSB specification](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/iniscrptfunc.html) specifies `log_success_msg` and `log_failure_msg` for this purpose. (Though of course many distros used _non_-LSB-conformant scripts...)

Answer (score 0):

This comes from distro-dependent init scripts. Check contents of `service` program, this is probably some shell script invoking underlying managements scripts (SysV are considered obsoleted now) or binaries (systemd is the way to go). This is one of the systemd pros - you won't get "that depends" answers.

Comment: ...because `systemctl start` has no feedback output whatsoever.

Comment: ... and it seems `systemctl` relies on `start-stop-daemon`.

Comment: No, systemctl doesn't rely on start-stop-daemon, unless you use some braindead distro.

Comment: No, that it doesn't. (The only time systemd runs start-stop-daemon is when there _isn't_ a native systemd .service file, and when it's forced to call the old /etc/init.d script – _those_ use start-stop-daemon if properly written.)

Comment: @grawity - yes, there is no output, as the `[OK]` message was nothing more than a lie, because it was only the status of some first-stage start, before forking and deamonization. Very often a deamon died seconds after that. The only message that was reliable was `[FAILED]`, which sometimes meant only, that the service ...was allready running, but the `service` command didn't know that.

Comment: Or, occassionally, [none of the above](https://i.imgur.com/xj9nWKx.png)

Comment: Good to know that :(